# Constant e and the natural log

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know that ln is simply the log with base e

I was wondering if someone could explain the math behind this conversion (how you can get from the first equation to the second one):

1.$e^{-kt}=0.92770^{t}$

2.$-kt=\ln{0.92700^{t}}$

Thank you very much

Comment: take $\ln$ of both sides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the first equation, we just take the natural log of both sides $$\ln{e^{-kt}}=\ln{0.92770^t}$$
which becomes $$-kt=\ln{0.92770^t}$$
which is equivalent to the desired second equation.

Answer (score 1):

To get from $x + 3 = 7$ to $x = 4$, we perform the inverse operation of addition, namely, *subtraction*.

To get from $5y = 30$ to $y = 6$, we perform the inverse operation of multiplication, namely, division.

To get from $e^{-kt} = 0.92770^t$, which is **exponentiation**, to $-kt = \ln(0.92770^t)$ we perform the inverse operation, which is called *taking the logarithm*. You take a logarithm of the same base as the base of the exponent. The notation for a log base $e$ is just $\ln$.

Answer (score 0):

> $$ e^{-kt}=0.92770^{t} $$

You can take the natural log of both sides of the equation: 
$$ ln(e^{-kt})=ln(0.92770^{t}) $$
An exponent inside a logarithm is equal to the same exponent multiplied by the existing logarithm with just the base:
$$ (-kt)ln(e)=ln(0.92770^{t}) $$
We know $ ln $ is just a logarithm with e as its base. So since the base is equal to e and the argument is equal to $ e $, then $ ln(e) =1 $. Making this substitution, we have:
 $$ (-kt)(1)=ln(0.92770^{t}) $$
Simplified, this equation is:
$$ -kt=ln(0.92770^{t}) $$
which is the equation in part b.